# Redirect to login page instead of dashboard, once the user logged out in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, session-variables

I created a http post request using an api and now I am having a minor issue. once I logout of the form, I can still access the home page without putting login details. the session does not expire even after logout. here is the code I am using in my login controller:

```js
var app = angular.module('LoginApp');
app.controller('loginController', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$window) {
    $scope.postdata = function () {
        var post = $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://api-stg.martcart.pk/api/v1/user/login",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                userName: $scope.username,
                password: $scope.password
            }),
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
        });
        post.success(function (data) {
            window.location='components/home/home.html';
               sessionStorage.setItem("authdata",JSON.stringify(data.token));
        });
        post.error(function () {
            alert("wrong credentials");
         });
    }
    $scope.logout = function(){
        // console.log("hello")
     window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5500/LoginAngularJS-API-master/index.html#/login';
     $window.sessionStorage.removeItem("authdata");
     
        //localStorage.removeItem("authdata");
        // $route.reload();
        // delete $window.sessionStorage;
        // $window.localStorage.clear();
        
    }
    
    
});
```

the logout.js function being called once logout button is clicked:

```js
function logout() {
  
    window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/LoginAngularJS-API-master/index.html#/login';
    sessionStorage.removeItem("authdata");
    // sessionStorage.destroy();   
   
    // localStorage.removeItem("authdata");
    //    delete $window.sessionStorage;
    //         $window.localStorage.clear();
}
```

will e glad if anyone could help trouble shoot the issue.
Thanks alot

Comment: This has nothing to do with visual studio code. Please remove the tag, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine time. Maybe try `sessionStorage.removeItem("authdata");`

without the $window.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but It still does not work.